# macports? where did it go?

Tags: macos, command-line

Through the process of installing Homebrew I moved a file. The command I ran was:

```
sudo mv /opt/local~/macports
```

My guess (because my command line/linux commands are limited) is that /opt/local has moved to /macports?

So should I just run the command reversed?

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with Linux. mv is Unix command and can thus be found in many operating systems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was `sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports` (with a space), then the reverse is

```
sudo mv ~/macports/local /opt
```

Comment: so I DO want to do reverse then right? and thanks for the edit

Comment: yes. I hope you didn't do anything that *recreated* your `/opt/local` (than my `mv` will fail).

Comment: just ran the one command listed. thanks for your help